# Maximum of product of two functions

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

Let's have two (real continuous differentiable) functions such that

1. $f(x)$ is bounded (from below and from above), positive ($f(x)>0$), and is strictly increasing ($f'(x)>0$, $\forall x$).
2. $g(x)$ is bounded (from below and from above) and has exactly one maximum ($g'(x_0) = 0$ ; $g(x)<g(x_0), \forall x \ne x_0$)

It then follows that function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ is also bounded. 
However, additional conditions on either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ must apply in order for the function $h(x)$ to have again only one maximum.

The question is. What are the additional sufficient conditions on either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ so that the product $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ would have again only one maximum?

(Thanks to gammatester for pointing this out).

Comment: Let $f(x) = \tan^{-1} x$, $g(x) = -x^2$.  These satisfy your criteria, but the product, being an odd function, does not.

Comment: @heropup I edited the question. $g(x)$ must be also bounded from below. $-x^2$ is not.

Comment: if $g'(x)<g'(x_0)=0$ for each $x\neq x_0$ then it has no maximum at $x_0$ and is strictly decreasing. To get a maximum the sign of the derivative must switch. You need $g'(x)>0$ if $x<x_0$ and $g'(x)<0$ if $x>x_0$.

Comment: @drhab Thanks for pointing out the error.

Comment: You can see that boundedness from below for $g$ *still* makes no difference:  e.g., $f(x) = \tan^{-1} x$, $g(x) = (1+x^2)^{-1} - 1$.  The product is still an odd function with no relative extremum.

Comment: @heropup Thanks for the example. You are right. If I may, does anything change when I put further condition on $f(x)$, that it has to be positive? In your case, e.g. $f(x)=\tan^{-1}x+1.5$, $g(x)=(1+x^2)^{-1}-1$.

Comment: @heropup, thanks for the examples but could you explain what is the link with odd functions, please?

Comment: If the function is odd, then any local extrema are symmetric on the real line.  This behavior would require at least two critical points, but it is easy to construct examples where we don't have that many, as I have shown.  It's not intended to be a rigorous argument or strict criterion.

Comment: You must put even stronger restrictions on $f,g.\;$ With
$$f(x)=\arctan(x)+2,\quad g(x)=\frac{1}{\arctan(x)^2-4}$$
all your requirements are met, but 
$$f(x)g(x)=\frac{1}{\arctan(x)-2}$$
has no maximum.

Comment: @gammatester Thanks. Very nice counterexample.

Comment: @gammatester I realized a somehow curious observation regarding your counterexample. If I add any (arbitrary small) positive constant $\epsilon$ to $g(x)$, then again $f(x)g(x)$ has only one maximum (given by $x^\star=\tan(2-\sqrt{1/\epsilon}$). So probably an additional condition on $g(x)$ may be quite ``mild'' and then the statement is correct.

Comment: Is it given that f is strictly increasing (meaning $x<y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$) or is it given that $f'(x)>0 \forall x$? These conditions are not equivalent. (x^3 is a counterexample)

Comment: @Stijn Strictly increasing ($x<y$ iff $f(x)<f(y)$). And also bounded. Function $f(x)$ is of type as e.g. $\arctan(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Dear @pisoir i think you need one easy condition or? read it.
$$h(x)=f(x)g(x)\\
h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$
The function $h(x)$ has a critical point if $h'(x)=0$, so
$$h'(x)=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)\\
=f'(x)\big\{ g(x)+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}*g'(x)\big\}$$
and we note  that  $f'(x)\ne0$ and that the fraction $\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$ is positive. The second derivative is
$$h''(x)=f''(x)g(x)+2f'(x)g'(x)+f(x)g''(x) \space $$
we have the following cases(i will get the local maximum and discuss conditions to be a unique and hence global maximum):
(1) $x < x_0:$ in this interval both $f$ and $g$ are increasing and $f$ is strictly increase so there is no local maximum of $h$ in this inteval.
(2) $x = x_0$: $g'(x_0)=0$ and ang $g''(x_0)$ is negative, so comparing both $h'(x),h''(x)$, the only case that $h$ has a maximum is that $g(x_0)=0$. notice that in this case it will be a global maximum of $h(x)$ since $g(x)$ will be negative elsewhere
(3) $x \gt x_0$: in this interval $g'(x)$ is negative and the local maximum holds only if
$$g(x)+\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}*g'(x)=0$$
from this equation we gett that $g$ is positive and hence $h''$ is negative if both $f''$ and $g''$ are negative. this case needs a deep discussion and is rare for general functions  to hold but you have a way to you complete.
A good graphical example for for two functions that have maximum product 10000 at infinity [image: An example]

Comment: I was hoping for a more "substantial" condition which is easy to check directly. Like (just a pure example) that if $g(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous (or anything) then it holds.

Comment: I was wondering. Could you maybe show, using your method, why for e.g. (see gammatester comment above)  $f(x)=\arctan(x)+2$, $g(x)=\frac{1}{(\arctan(x))^2-4}$ there is no maximum for $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$?

Comment: (First i didn't check the conditions of both functions, i assumed it holds). The first case to have a maximum is $g(x_0)=0$ is not valid since $g(0)=-1/4$

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying $g$ has just one maximum, I think it means that $g$ has no other point of maximum/minimum.

So the function increases to $g(x_0)$ and then decreases.

For $f$ it just goes on increasing.

$$ f(x)g(x) < f(x_0)g(x_0) \; \forall \; x \neq x_0 $$

Also check for $(f(x)g(x))'$ to be $0$ at $x = x_0$ we also need $g(x_0) = 0$.

So the conditions would be :

1) $ f(x)g(x) < f(x_0)g(x_0) \; \forall \; x \neq x_0 $ and

2) $g(x_0) = 0$.

which can be summarized in 2) only, i.e. $g(x_0) = 0$.

But we do not yet guaranteed that maxima is just one in this case.

If we need that there should be no other minima as well :

then $$ (f(x)g(x))' = 0 \; iff \;  x = x_0 .$$

We analyse it over the 3 regions :

i) $x < x_0$ where $f'(x) > 0$ and $f(x) > 0$, $g(x) < 0$ and $g'(x) > 0$ ;

ii) $x = x_0$ and

iii) $x > x_0$ where $f'(x) > 0$ and $f(x) > 0$, $g(x) < 0$ and $g'(x) < 0$ ;

and ensure that in i) and ii) the condition does not hold.

$$ (f(x)g(x))' = f'(x)g(x) + g'(x)f(x) $$ is negative in region iii) so we do not have a min or maxima.

but in region i) the first term is negative while the last term is positive, so we have as all the quantities are positive,

$$f'(x)/g'(x) \neq - f(x)/g(x) \; for \; x < x_0.$$ for making the expression non-zero.

So the final conditions are :

1) $g(x_0) = 0$ and

2) $f'(x)/g'(x) \neq - f(x)/g(x) \; for \; x < x_0$.

Comment: the first one is incorrect ingeneral

Comment: @Semsem : Good now ?

Comment: I think no @Diffeor

Comment: @Semsem : Probably this is the best to offer if there are no serious mistakes. You have assumed double differentiability (an extra assumption) in your proof which I have tried to avoid here.

Comment: @pisoir : Is it simple enough now ?

Comment: my point is if 1 is true then we get the max. and this will not happen and i construct a counter example example // the domain in the new analysis seems to be strange

Comment: @semsem : Yes I agree your condition is on region iii) and mine is on region i) and they are similar conditions except that you have gone to second derivative. Surely one of us is mistaken ! But who ?

It would be nice to know if you have a counterexample here.

Comment: I add an example to my answer. Formy last comment, I wonder what does $x_0-\mathbb{R}_+$ mean?. Finally i hope that your answer is correct, in both cases i will learn some new and some true

Comment: Oh! that is just $(\infty, x_0)$, set obtained by subtracting positive real numbers one at a time from $x_0$.

Comment: @DiffeoR you mean $(-\infty, x_0)$? Maybe you could use "for $x<x_0$" in your answer, so it is better readible? The same for $x_0 +R_+$.

Comment: Now is it readable guys ? Yes your notation saves a lot of space indeed.

Comment: @semsem : I looked at the graph of your example and I am quite sure now that condition in region i) in my case is correct. :)

Comment: @pisoir : Are you still not satisfied with the answer ?

Comment: @DiffeoR Looking at your final conditions. Are you saying that in the case those two conditions are satisfied then the product has also one maximum? The condition that $g(x_0)=0$ (maximum is zero) is quite strict.

Comment: @pisoir : Yes, indeed. Reasoning is explained in the answer $h'(x_0)$ to be zero, there is no other way but to make $g(x_0) = 0$.

Comment: @DiffeoR In your conditions you have $g(x_0)=0$, not $g^\prime(x_0)=0$. Condition $g^\prime(x_0)=0$ is just the condition on $g(x)$ which means that $g(x)$ has a maximum (it's already written in question..).

Comment: @pisoir : If you think it's a valid answer, then you should mark it as an answer ??

Comment: @pisoir : I had put derivative mistakenly in the comment. Now I have corrected the comment.

Comment: @DiffeoR Well, but such condition is obviously not true. For e.g. $g(x)=\frac{1}{(\arctan(x))^2-4}+0.5$ then $g(x_0)=0.25$. Having $f(x)=\arctan(x)+2$ then $f(x)g(x)$ has exactly one maximum (it can be found analytically).

Comment: @pisoir : $f$ is not positive ?

Comment: @pisoir : Sorry my bad.

Comment: @DiffeoR It is. $f(x)=arctan(x)+2$ is a positive function.

Comment: @pisoir : Here some subtle points are : It is not about maximum, minimum is to be eliminated also. I am not sure if that is the case here. Also one thing in my prove I tried to  keep the global maximum at $x_0$. If you need max at $x_0$ I don't see how you avoid $g(x_0) = 0$ ??

Comment: @DiffeoR I don't want to keep maximum at $x_0$. I just want to ensure that there is _some_ maximum. As a counterexample, when you slightly change the $g(x)$ (still having one maximum) then suddenly there is no maximum at all in the product (see gammatester comment at the top answer).